# zlib implementation difference between nodejs [13.13.0] and ruby [2.5.1p57]

Tags: node.js, ruby, git, zlib

I am learning the internals of git, and this is a tree in my repository:

```
git cat-file 88e38705fdbd3608cddbe904b67c731f3234c45b -p
100644 blob ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a    hello.txt
100644 blob cc628ccd10742baea8241c5924df992b5c019f71    world.txt
```

When I use Ruby's zlib with:

```
puts Zlib::Inflate.inflate(STDIN.read)
```

and pipe the output with `hexdump -C`:

```
cat .git/objects/88/e38705fdbd3608cddbe904b67c731f3234c45b | rinflate | hexdump -C
```

this is the output:

```
00000000  74 72 65 65 20 37 34 00  31 30 30 36 34 34 20 68  |tree 74.100644 h|
00000010  65 6c 6c 6f 2e 74 78 74  00 ce 01 36 25 03 0b a8  |ello.txt...6%...|
00000020  db a9 06 f7 56 96 7f 9e  9c a3 94 46 4a 31 30 30  |....V......FJ100|
00000030  36 34 34 20 77 6f 72 6c  64 2e 74 78 74 00 cc 62  |644 world.txt..b|
00000040  8c cd 10 74 2b ae a8 24  1c 59 24 df 99 2b 5c 01  |...t+..$.Y$..+\.|
00000050  9f 71                                             |.q|
00000052
```

However, when I use NodeJS:

```
  const zlib = require("zlib");
  const fs = require("fs");
  fs.writeFileSync("/dev/stdout", zlib.inflateSync(fs.readFileSync("/dev/stdin")).toString());
```

I get this output:

```
00000000  74 72 65 65 20 37 34 00  31 30 30 36 34 34 20 68  |tree 74.100644 h|
00000010  65 6c 6c 6f 2e 74 78 74  00 ef bf bd 01 36 25 03  |ello.txt.....6%.|
00000020  0b ef bf bd db a9 06 ef  bf bd 56 ef bf bd 7f ef  |..........V.....|
00000030  bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd  ef bf bd 46 4a 31 30 30  |...........FJ100|
00000040  36 34 34 20 77 6f 72 6c  64 2e 74 78 74 00 ef bf  |644 world.txt...|
00000050  bd 62 ef bf bd ef bf bd  10 74 2b ef bf bd ef bf  |.b.......t+.....|
00000060  bd 24 1c 59 24 df 99 2b  5c 01 ef bf bd 71        |.$.Y$..+\....q|
```

Why this difference? And how can I make NodeJS and Ruby output the same thing?

Comment: Looks like node is trying to interpret the data as UTF-8 and adding unicode replacement characters (which has the bytes EF BF BD in UTF-8). Does using `.toString('binary')` instead of plain `.toString()` work?

Comment: @matt, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried different encoding with toString(), nothing worked. So I removed toString() altogether and it worked! Now the output is same for the Ruby and NodeJS version, though I am not sure why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, a string is a sequence of Unicode characters encoded in UTF-16.  You can't store non-text content in a JavaScript string, since it doesn't provide a way to store in any other encoding.

However, Git tree objects are binary and contain a cryptographic hash in binary format (usually SHA-1), so they aren't going to have text content and can't be stored in a JavaScript string.  If you try to do so anyway, you're going to get invalid byte values replaced by U+FFFD, the replacement character, which is encoded in UTF-8 as 0xef 0xbf 0xbd, corrupting the data.

If you don't call `toString()`, your data is stored in some sort of binary buffer object and has exactly the bytes that zlib decoded.

Ruby, on the other hand, has an encoding per string and can store binary strings with the encoding `ASCII-8BIT` (also known as `BINARY`).  So if you had Ruby code, this would probably work just fine.

Comment: Thanks but I am able to change the encoding of the string like this: Buffer.toString('binary'), So does this change the string to UTF-16 and then to binary?

Comment: `binary` doesn't prevent it from being encoded into UTF-16, it just interprets the bytes as Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1).  Your string will still be UTF-16 and it may or may not provide correct results.  Don't use a string for non-text data.